# Tensorflow 2.3.0 CUDA Toolkit version 10.1 does not use GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had tensorflow 2.0 workig with my RTX2070 gpu. I did a windows update so I could use tf-nightly. Did not like it so uninstalled it and reinstalled tensorflow 2.3.0. Ran previous python code that ran fine with GPU previously but it did not use the GPU. Tried lots of stuff. Finally just started over. Reinstalled Anaconda, created new environment. Uninstalled Cuda toolkit 10.1 and reinstalled it. Installed cuDnn SDK 7.6 in directory c:\Tools. Checked path env variable to include

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include;
C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
       #then ran this code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print(tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
     #I get the result
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 15177607927005893519
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 4640072765546557805
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 16675502319763286567
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
2.3.0
Num GPUs Available:  0

False

tensorflow still does not use GPU. What an I missing? 

also same problem using python 3.7.0 and same problem using tensorflow 2.0.0
```

Comment: 1. [verify](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#verify-installation) cuda install  2. confirm that you don't have any `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variables set

Comment: Cuda tooolkit v 10.1 created the associated directories so it installed. There are no environment variables of the type you mentioned. Why does it show the GPU as XLA-GPU?

Comment: What is the python version that you are using?

Comment: version is 3.8.3

Comment: also tried using python 3.7.0 still have the problem. Then tried tensorflow 2.0.0 and still have the problem

Comment: This has something to do with the XLA compiler being enable by setting  an environmental variable as in $ TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_auto_jit=2 path/to/your/tf/program. I can't find where this is happening

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found I can get tensorflow to recognize the GPU if in my working environment using conda I run conda install cudnn==7.6.4 which works with CUDA 10.1.0 resultant  messages in anaconda prompt are:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\tfuser\anaconda3\envs\tf

  added / updated specs:
    - cudnn==7.6.4


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cudnn-7.6.4                |       cuda10.1_0       179.3 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       179.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cudatoolkit        pkgs/main/win-64::cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h74a9793_0
  cudnn              pkgs/main/win-64::cudnn-7.6.4-cuda10.1_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y
The following packages will be downloaded:
 cudnn-7.6.4                |       cuda10.1_0       179.3 MB
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cudatoolkit        pkgs/main/win-64::cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h74a9793_0
  cudnn              pkgs/main/win-64::cudnn-7.6.4-cuda10.1_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Downloading and Extracting Packages
cudnn-7.6.4          | 179.3 MB  |
Preparing transaction: doneVerifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Comment: successfully install tensorflow-gpu 2.3 with cudatoolkit 10.1 with on my cuda 10.2 driver with below commands: `conda install cudnn==7.6.4` then `pip install tensorflow-gpu=2.3` Note: remember to activate your conda env and install pip for anaconda `conda install pip`

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Azure N-series DSVM was not showing GPU availability, despite using the DS image. Adding `cudnn=7.6.4` to my conda environment fixed it. I could then use tensorflow 2.3 to train my models.

Comment: Amazing!
Worked like a charm, absolutely solves the issue of manually fine-tuning the version of all the components!

Ubuntu 16.04
TensorFlow 2.3
CUDA 10.1