# Keras on GPU on windows with python 3.7.13

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I had to reinstall completely my python distribution lately and for some reasons I cannot run keras on GPU anymore.

I followed the instructions from [Can I run Keras model on gpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662253/can-i-run-keras-model-on-gpu) but for some reason, I do not see my GPU when trying to list the devices.

my versions are :

- tensorflow & tensorflow-gpu : 2.3.0
- keras : 2.3.1
- cudatoolkit : 11.3.1

I have not installed cudnn yet as the instructions are a bit blurry for me : do I have to install it in the cudatoolkit directory ? Is it required to run on GPU ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for GPU compatibility with cuda sdk ? https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. Also make sure your GPU's drivers are up to date

Comment: You need to have cuDNN installed.

Comment: I installed cudNN also according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63240027/tensorflow-2-3-0-cuda-toolkit-version-10-1-does-not-use-gpu but it still does not work. Also my script formerly running with keras now return a tensorflow error. I think I might have a version nconstitency issue. Where can I find a version compatibility list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here is the solution :

Python 3.7.13 requires tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0 to detect gpu.
So the correct set of versions is :

- Python 3.7.13
- tensorflow 2.1.0
- keras 2.3.0
- cudnn 7.6.5
- cudatoolkit 10.1.243

with this it works. Be careful that for some reason, in my case tensorflow downloaded tensorflow-estimator 2.6.0. I had to downgrade to 2.1.0 to get spyder running.